# Проблема с более низким пониманием уровня GetCmdOption(argv, argv + argc, "--input")

Tags: c++, qt, argv

Столкнулся с проблемой апробации одного проекта с GitHub (https://github.com/dspavankumar/compute-mfcc).

Суть такова:

1. Скомпилировал (Windows 10, Qt, MinGW 5.9.1);
2. Запустил;
3. Получил:

   [image: Вывод экрана. А именно нотацию о том что ничего не вышло(я так думаю)]

Не отрабатывает следующий участок кода:

```
// Main
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
std::string USAGE = "compute-mfcc : MFCC Extractor\n";
USAGE += "OPTIONS\n";
USAGE += "--input           : Input 16 bit PCM Wave file\n";
USAGE += "--output          : Output MFCC file in CSV format, each frame in a line\n";
USAGE += "--inputlist       : List of input Wave files\n";
USAGE += "--outputlist      : List of output MFCC CSV files\n";
USAGE += "--numcepstra      : Number of output cepstra, excluding log-energy (default=12)\n";
USAGE += "--numfilters      : Number of Mel warped filters in filterbank (default=40)\n";
USAGE += "--samplingrate    : Sampling rate in Hertz (default=16000)\n";
USAGE += "--winlength       : Length of analysis window in milliseconds (default=25)\n";
USAGE += "--frameshift      : Frame shift in milliseconds (default=10)\n";
USAGE += "--lowfreq         : Filterbank low frequency cutoff in Hertz (default=50)\n";
USAGE += "--highfreq        : Filterbank high freqency cutoff in Hertz (default=samplingrate/2)\n";
USAGE += "USAGE EXAMPLES\n";
USAGE += "compute-mfcc --input input.wav --output output.mfc\n";
USAGE += "compute-mfcc --input input.wav --output output.mfc --samplingrate 8000\n";
USAGE += "compute-mfcc --inputlist input.list --outputlist output.list\n";
USAGE += "compute-mfcc --inputlist input.list --outputlist output.list --numcepstra 17 --samplingrate 44100\n";

char *wavPath = getCmdOption(argv, argv+argc, "--input");
char *mfcPath = getCmdOption(argv, argv+argc, "--output");
char *wavListPath = getCmdOption(argv, argv+argc, "--inputlist");
```

И так далее.

Срабатывает код, говорящий о том, что мои указатели пустые, с последующим выводом нотации и `return`:

```
if(!wavPath)
    std::cout<<"-wav \n";
if(!mfcPath)
    std::cout<<"-mfc \n";

// Check arguments
if ((argc<3) || (!(wavPath && mfcPath) && !(wavListPath && mfcListPath))) {
    std::cout << USAGE;
    return 1;
}
```

Пробовал вводить различную информацию, в третий аргумент функции `GetCmdOption()`. Вот и она сама:

```
// A simple option parser
char* getCmdOption(char **begin, char **end, const std::string &value) {
char **iter = std::find(begin, end, value);
if (iter != end && ++iter != end)
    return *iter;
return nullptr;
}
```

Реальный `input.wav` разложил во всевозможные папки, выходной файл тоже кинул. Но в итоге указатели все равно пустые и постоянно лезет нотация, которая пишет о примере использования. Пробовал писать сначала так:

```
char *wavPath = getCmdOption(argv, argv+argc, "input.wav");
```

Потом так:

```
char *wavPath = getCmdOption(argv, argv+argc, "--input input.wav");
```

Ничего не получилось. В чём здесь проблема?

Comment: Дык, а в аргументы при запуске программы то что именно передаёшь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам вывод в консоли говорит, что не заданы аргументы командной строки. Их не нужно задавать как стандартный ввод или в коде. Судя по заголовку окна на скриншоте вы используете QtCreator, там для задания аргументов командной строки для запуска программы нужно зайти на вкладку projects, в текущую конфигурацию запуска, там выбрать run, и в появившееся поле для ввода аргументов ввести то, что нужно.

Чуть понятнее на скриншоте:
[image]